# Password_verify not matching database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-password-hash

I have looked at the other questions/answers to do with this and have tried to modify my code multiple ways to suit their answers, but have had no success. I have a register form that works fine and successfully adds the user to the database using the password_hash function. Password field is VARCHAR(255) and displays as hashed when entered.

The issue is with the login form. I have tried various ways all day with no success. Below is my current login.php script.

```php
<?php

 session_start(); // Starting Session

$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

//error if both boxes empty
if (empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
$error = "Please fill in both boxes";
}
else
{

// connecting, selecting database
require_once 'dbstuff.php';
include 'opendb.php';

// To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose and  define $email and $password
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn,$_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn,$_POST['password']);


//selects user = to email given
$sel_user = "SELECT * from Customer WHERE email='$email'";

$result = $cxn->query($sel_user);

//if matched email in DB verifies password given with hashed password in DB
if($result->num_rows ===1){
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])){

    echo "match";
//$_SESSION['login_user']=$email; // Initializing Session
//header("location: index.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
} else {
$error = "email or Password is invalid";
}
}
mysqli_close($cxn); // Closing Connection
}
}

?>
```

$error variable works fine but still can't see where I am going wrong with the password_verify, keep getting the 'email or password is invalid' error instead of 'match'.

I really would appreciate some feedback on what I have missed out in the code! Thanks :)

Comment: you don't need to escape the password unless you are passing it in a query directly. Plus if you had a character that gets escaped, your password would now have an escape character and not match the stored hash unless you escaped it before hashing (which isn't necessary).

Comment: The above comment is the answer.

Comment: I honestly figured it was a long shot only because there are only a few characters that need escaping. So while that is one issue, IMO it is unlikely the final issue unless OP has like a quote in their password they are testing with.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Thought it might be something silly and that makes sense, so changing the variable to -
$password = $_POST['password']; - to stop escaping the password should work? I still get invalid email/pass error when I change code to that. Sorry if i am misunderstanding you!

Comment: What size is the database password column?

Comment: 528, should I increase it?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was saying you should do. And when you are storing the password in the database are you hashing it with the `password_hash` function?

Comment: I am using - 
$query = mysqli_query("insert into Customer(firstName, email, password) values ('$firstName', '$email', '".password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)."')"); 

- And when reading the database i can see that the relevant info has been inserted and password has been hashed.

Comment: have you verified that the correct password hash is actually being stored? ie, compared the hash generated to the value inserted, immediately after it is inserted?

Comment: @pala_ you are right, thanks. The correct hash isn't being stored so there is something wrong with my register script not login (not until register is sorted anyway) I'll work on that and hopefully this login script should run fine. Thanks for your time and advice everyone!

Comment: Yeah, was just going to say that I've tested your code and I didn't have a problem with it. Make sure the stored hash doesn't contain a space somewhere, or that it isn't being mangled by anything along the way. Certain functions will do just that and strip out characters thinking they're bad.